# hide an android textview based on property

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to hide a textView based on a property value. There is a 'creditCard' model object imported into xml layout as a variable

```
  <TextView
      android:text="@={ creditCard.name }"
      android:visibility="@{ creditCard.name}" />
```

Is this a right way to show/hide view elements based on property value null/empty?

Comment: The value for visibility should be any one from `0`, `1`or `2`. It can not be a string. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextView
      android:text="@={ creditCard.name }"
      android:visibility="@{ creditCard.hasName()}" />
```

And your method that inside CreditCard class should look like;

```
public int hasName(){
      return TextUtils.isEmpty(mName) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE
}
```

Good luck there

Emre